# spyder doesn't launch after installing pytorch

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, pytorch

I installed pytorch but after that Spyder can no longer be launched. Here are the terminal info:

> conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch Solving environment: done
>
> ==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==   current version: 4.5.10   latest version: 4.5.11
>
> Please update conda by running
>
> ```
> $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
> ```
>
> ### Package Plan
>
> environment location: /anaconda3/envs/base_py36
>
> added / updated specs: 
>       - pytorch
>       - torchvision
>
> The following packages will be downloaded:
>
> ```
> package                    |            build
> ---------------------------|-----------------
> torchvision-0.2.1          |           py36_1         123 KB  pytorch
> scipy-1.1.0                |   py36hf1f7d93_0        15.4 MB
> scikit-learn-0.20.0        |   py36h4f467ca_1         5.4 MB
> numpy-base-1.15.2          |   py36h8a80b8c_1         4.1 MB
> numpy-1.11.3               |   py36heee0a97_5         3.4 MB
> ninja-1.8.2                |   py36h04f5b5a_1          93 KB
> pytorch-0.4.1              |py36_cuda0.0_cudnn0.0_1        10.0 MB  pytorch
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>                                        Total:        38.5 MB
> ```
>
> The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
>
> ```
> ninja:        1.8.2-py36h04f5b5a_1                 
> pytorch:      0.4.1-py36_cuda0.0_cudnn0.0_1 pytorch
> torchvision:  0.2.1-py36_1                  pytorch
> ```
>
> The following packages will be REMOVED:
>
> ```
> accelerate:   2.3.1-np111py36_0
> ```
>
> The following packages will be UPDATED:
>
> ```
> mkl:          11.3.3-0                              --> 2019.0-118           
> numexpr:      2.6.7-py36hde7755b_0                  --> 2.6.8-py36h1dc9127_0 
> numpy:        1.11.3-py36_nomklh8ecaf62_5           --> 1.11.3-py36heee0a97_5
> numpy-base:   1.15.0-py36he97cb71_0                 --> 1.15.2-py36h8a80b8c_1
> scikit-learn: 0.19.1-py36_nomklhde7755b_0           --> 0.20.0-py36h4f467ca_1
> scipy:        1.1.0-py36_nomklh7cd7d8e_0            --> 1.1.0-py36hf1f7d93_0
> ```
>
> The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
>
> ```
> blas:         1.0-openblas                          --> 1.0-mkl
> ```
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
> Downloading and Extracting Packages torchvision-0.2.1    | 123 KB    |
>
> ############################### | 100%  scipy-1.1.0          | 15.4 MB   | ##################################### | 100%  scikit-learn-0.20.0  | 5.4 MB    |
>   
>   ############################### | 100%  numpy-base-1.15.2    | 4.1 MB    | ##################################### | 100%  numpy-1.11.3         | 3.4 MB    | ##################################### | 100%
>
> ninja-1.8.2          | 93 KB     |
>
> ############################### | 100%  pytorch-0.4.1        | 10.0 MB   | ##################################### | 100%  Preparing transaction: done

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I don't know the source of this problem, but things like this can be very easily avoided if you use a [conda environment](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) to install `pytorch`. So my recommendation is for you to remove and reinstall Anaconda, then install Pytorch in a conda env, and finally [point Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#the-modular-approach) to your Pytorch env.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have solved your issue, but in case you have and someone else comes across this question or you haven't and are still waiting:

I came across your post as a result of having the same thing happen to me...

It would seem that all I had to do was "conda update all" for it to start working again!

Answer (score 0):

I came across it too. And I tried reopen Anaconda Navigator and it worked....